# /replace unspecific item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to test if the player has say, an empty bucket in their inventory, and replace it with a filled lava bucket. It only works if the stack size of the buckets is 1, and works in any inventory or hotbar slot.

I have a similar working command:
/replaceitem entity @a slot.hotbar.8 minecraft:wool 1 11 {HideFlags:1,ench:[{id:71,lvl:1}]}

But this does 2 things wrong: first, it sets hotbar slot 8 to wool regardless of what is already in that slot, and it only sets slot 8 specifically.

Edit: I'm on 1.12

Comment: And what is your question? Apart from that, the two things you mention seem unrelated: what is their connection?

Comment: "I would like to test if the player has say, an empty bucket in their inventory, and replace it with a filled lava bucket."
"This does 2 things wrong: first, it sets hotbar slot 8 to wool regardless of what is already in that slot, and it only sets slot 8 specifically."

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that dynamically, you need one command per item. You basically need the commands from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/368284/171580).